# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':xxx:check'

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project using Gradle 1.12, it goes well using `gradle assemble`, but exception occurs when executing `gradle build` as follows:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':JavaUtil:check'.
> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.getTaskName() is applicable for
rgument types: (java.lang.String, null) values: [findbugs, null]
Possible solutions: getName()
```

Having the dependencies settings in gradle script of `JavaUtil's` parent folder like this:

```
dependencies {
        compile (project (':JavaUtil')) {transitive = false}
```

The same error occurs when I executed `gradle build` in `JavaUtil` folder.

Any ideas what happens here?

Comment: It seems that is has nothing in common with `dependencies`. Please provide the whole script.

Comment: What's the possibly cause you think?

Comment: Exception message indicates that it's rather a problem with code quality plugin. Please provide an example that reproduces the problem. It's called SSCCE.

Comment: @Opal I'm just trying to build a new project which has lots of scripts, so it's not good to post it here. This error message occurs when I try to build it with `gradle build', but it works running with 'gradle assemble`. From the message, I checked the `JavaUtil` and tried to build it, `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':JavaUtil:check'` occurs, so I want to know where's the possible cause of this?